# How to remove magazine unlock on huawei p9 running nougat

Tags: lock-screens, 7.0-nougat, huawei

How can I completely remove the magazine unlock that comes with Android 7.0 (nougat) on a huawei P9. I want my phone to go directly to the pattern unlock screen and not show the magazine unlock.

I am willing to root the phone if required to delete/replace this screen.

I am running build EVA-L09C432B386 and have TWRP recovery installed.

Comment: FYI I fixed this problem myself, but I have no idea how. Not much help I know!

Answer (score 0):

The earlier answer didnt work for me. What I ended up doing was on my lock screen, I swiped up from the bottom to access the lock screen settings. Under "Subscriptions", I unsubscribed from all subscriptions, turned off the auto-update AND turned on the option to delete all old cover pictures, just to be thorough.

Then I went back to my lock screen, swiped up again and accessed "Covers", and I deleted all of them.

Hope this helps someone. I was getting pretty frustrated in trying to figure this out.

Answer (score -1):

1. From your device’s Settings, tap Screen lock & password > Magazine unlock.
2. Turn off ‘Auto-update via Wi-Fi’

Found it in this link:
http://webcazine.com/forums/honor-8-how-to-turn-off-wallpaper-updates/

Comment: PLS Note that i have tried this method on my Huawei mate 9, and it did not work.